# Reading in a pretty-printed/formatted dataframe using pd.read_clipboard?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, clipboard

Here's a dataframe from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856687/subtract-a-year-if-the-previous-month-was-january):

```
+--------------------+---------------+-------+
|   Location         | Date          | Value |
+--------------------+---------------+-------+
| India              | 2015-03-15    |   -200|
| India              | 2015-02-15    |  140  |
| India              | 2015-01-15    |  155  |
| India              | 2015-12-15    |   85  |
| India              | 2015-11-15    |   45  |
| China              | 2015-03-15    |   199 |
| China              | 2015-02-15    |  164  |
| China              | 2015-01-15    |  209  |
| China              | 2015-12-15    |   24  |
| China              | 2015-11-15    |   11  |
| Russia             | 2015-03-15    |   48  |
| Russia             | 2015-02-15    |  104  |
| Russia             | 2015-01-15    |  106  |
| Russia             | 2015-12-15    |   -20 |
| Russia             | 2015-11-15    |   10  |
+--------------------+---------------+-------+
```

And, for the sake of convenience, here's the version that you can copy without any problems:

```
   Location        Date  Value
0     India  2015-03-15   -200
1     India  2015-02-15    140
2     India  2015-01-15    155
3     India  2015-12-15     85
4     India  2015-11-15     45
5     China  2015-03-15    199
6     China  2015-02-15    164
7     China  2015-01-15    209
8     China  2015-12-15     24
9     China  2015-11-15     11
10   Russia  2015-03-15     48
11   Russia  2015-02-15    104
12   Russia  2015-01-15    106
13   Russia  2015-12-15    -20
14   Russia  2015-11-15     10
```

How would you read it in using `df.read_clipboard` without having to manually remove all those delimiters and row separators?

This would've been easy using `sep` or `delimiter` if it were not for the `---+----`.

Comment: this is interesting... I'll try to find a solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [129]: pd.read_clipboard(comment='+', sep='\s*\|\s*', usecols=[1,2,3], engine='python')
Out[129]:
   Location        Date  Value
0     India  2015-03-15   -200
1     India  2015-02-15    140
2     India  2015-01-15    155
3     India  2015-12-15     85
4     India  2015-11-15     45
5     China  2015-03-15    199
6     China  2015-02-15    164
7     China  2015-01-15    209
8     China  2015-12-15     24
9     China  2015-11-15     11
10   Russia  2015-03-15     48
11   Russia  2015-02-15    104
12   Russia  2015-01-15    106
13   Russia  2015-12-15    -20
14   Russia  2015-11-15     10
```

Comment: Nice! Were you able to figure out how they were printed that way in the first place?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, PySpark usually does it per default, but i don't know how to do that in Pandas...