# Apply groupby on a DataFrame to display cumulative stats

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
Bank Name     House     This Wk
Barc          Germany   100
Barc          UK        300
Barc          UK        500
JPM           Japan     200
JPM           NYC       100
BOA           LA        900
BOA           LA        50
BOA           LA        50
DB            Italy     45
```

I would like to group-by Bank Name, while outputting the largest House Value as well as the total value...

For example, using the example above would result in:

```
Bank Name     Total     House     This Wk
Barc          900       UK        500
JPM           300       Japan     200
BOA           1000      LA        900
DB            45        Italy     45
```

Essentially, it is grouping the `Total` by Bank Name, but also outputting the largest contributor, `House`, to the total and the amount contributed is `This Wk`.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: in what format is DataFrame?

Comment: @ands literally similar to the one above.. what do you mean what format?

Comment: is it string like in text document?

Comment: No it's coming from a csv - Bank Name and House are strings, the others are floats

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider `df.groupby` with a list of `dfGroupBy.agg` functions:

```
In [732]: out = df.groupby('Bank Name')['This Wk'].agg(['sum', 'idxmax', 'max'])\
               .rename(columns={'sum' : 'Total', 'idxmax' : 'House', 'max' : 'This Wk'})\
               .reset_index()


In [734]: out['House'] = df.loc[out['House'], 'House'].values; out
Out[734]: 
  Bank Name  Total  House  This Wk
0       BOA   1000     LA      900
1      Barc    900     UK      500
2        DB     45  Italy       45
3       JPM    300  Japan      200
```

Comment: How would I keep the format as the one I showed above, meaning the columns are  `Bank Name, Total, House, This Wk`?

Comment: Not just rename, how do I change the order of the columns?

Comment: Oh, that's really simple. Just change the order of the agg functions.

Comment: @sgerbhctim Fixed with order too.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ for the print , you can try `import tabulate from tabulate

print(tabulate.tabulate(df, df.columns, tablefmt="orgtbl"))`

Comment: @Wen Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

```
In [121]: df.groupby('Bank Name', group_keys=False) \
     ...:   .apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1, 'This Wk').assign(Total=x['This Wk'].sum())) \
     ...:   [['Bank Name','Total','House','This Wk']]
     ...:
Out[121]:
  Bank Name  Total  House  This Wk
5       BOA   1000     LA      900
2      Barc    900     UK      500
8        DB     45  Italy       45
3       JPM    300  Japan      200
```

Comment: Any chance you can format it the way I showed..? As in the columns: `Bank Name, Total, House, This Wk`?

Comment: And can I just set the result to equal a different dataframe?

Comment: Notice the order of column names and their respective values

Comment: @sgerbhctim, i've updated my post - is that what you need?

Comment: Yo how's it going. Any thoughts? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856926/reading-in-a-pretty-printed-formatted-dataframe-using-pd-read-clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `apply` would be

```
In [17]: (df.groupby('Bank Name', sort=False)
            .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(
                             [x['This Wk'].sum(), 
                              x.loc[x['This Wk'].idxmax(), 'House'], 
                              x['This Wk'].max()], 
                   index=['Total', 'House', 'This Wk']))
            .reset_index())
Out[17]:
  Bank Name  Total  House  This Wk
0      Barc    900     UK      500
1       JPM    300  Japan      200
2       BOA   1000     LA      900
3        DB     45  Italy       45
```